# c# and libraries from python

Tags: c#, tensorflow

Does `C#` have a library that can reproduce the same thing?

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

Functions to reproduce:

```
# A utility function to decode the output of the network
def decode_batch_predictions(pred):
    input_len = np.ones(pred.shape[0]) * pred.shape[1]
    # Use greedy search. For complex tasks, you can use beam search
    results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][:, :max_length]

    # Iterate over the results and get back the text
    output_text = []
    for res in results:
        res = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(res)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        output_text.append(res)
    return output_text
```

The situation is as follows. I trained the model, it works fine. But I haven 't found a way to decode the model 's response in the environment yet .NET ;(

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Imo you can make api integration between your python app and c# app

Comment: @MaythamFahmi Thanks! I didn't think about it, I'll try to study this moment. But I have already transferred it and can send data to it, but I can't find a way to decode the response (